# Node / Express 4 middleware not working

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-generator

I have an app generated with express-generator, with a bin/www file and a app.js file. In the app.js, I added the following:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
      console.log("--------new middleware");
      next();
    });
```

But it's not calling the middleware at all. The rest of the app works fine and I've confirmed that the server is running and receiving requests.

Here is the app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

//lots of routes

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({ secret: 'separation anxiety' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

//lots of paths

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log("--------new middleware");
  next();
});

// app.use(auth.isLoggedIn);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You have the wrong function signature for middleware.  There is no `err` argument.  See http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Comment: as per my post above I tried it without as well (..I also tried this without the err in the front). I should make it more clear.

Comment: Is your server even running?  Are you getting any requests?  If `app.get('/', ...)` does not even work, then your server is probably not running or not intiialized properly.  Your second code block is correct and will work if other things are done correctly.  So, if that second code block isn't work, then there's something else wrong in your code that you have not disclosed.  We will have to see the rest of your code to know what else is wrong.

Comment: this second one you wrote works just fine. make sure your server is running

Comment: The server is running and all paths work correctly, it's an entire API. I just have no idea why the middleware is not getting called.

Comment: @Mankind1023 you probably added your middleware somewhere at the bottom of `app.js`, is that correct?

Comment: Can you post the app.js file? May be the problem is the order of middleware use.

Comment: I tried adding before and after the functions generated by express, currently it's just above the //catch 404 and forward to error handler

Comment: I added the whole app.js to the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An important thing to know about Express middleware is that it's called in order of declaration.

If any of the declared middleware handles a request (by sending back a response), the request isn't passed to any middleware declared after the one handling the request.

So if you add a "catch-all" middleware after all the other middleware has been declared, chances are that no request will ever get passed to your middleware, because it got handled somewhere else.

To fix this, declare your middleware somewhere "high up" in the middleware chain. In your case, try declaring it before `express.static`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log("--------new middleware");
  next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

It will depend on the ultimate goal of your middleware what the correct place in the middleware chain will be.

Or, since you added the middleware right above the 404 handler, try requesting a non-existent URL from your server; that should trigger your middleware as well.

Comment: So requesting a non-existent URL did trigger it, any way to make this run on every call or at least every route?

Comment: @Mankind1023 yes, move it to above where your routes are declared.

Comment: Ok so putting this on the top of the file seems to do the trick, thanks!